# Применение нейронных сетей и ИИ в Мобильных Приложениях.

Tags: java, android, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать , примеры приложений , да и в целом, где и как применяются нейронные сети и ИИ в приложениях. 
Сам пишу на java под android, и хотелось бы узнать, реально ли совмещать данные занятия:"Изучение нейронных сетей и ИИ и практиковаться и внедрять их в Мобильных Приложениях?

Comment: ИИ это не только нейронные сети. Какие задачи Вы хотите решать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как показала моя практика это возможно, однако писать нейросеть в самом приложении не самая лучшая идея. Когда начинал изучение нейросетей, с 0 написал свою нейросеть в виде библеотеки для андроид. Использую ее в 2 своих проектах: анализ рынка акций и анализ предпочтений фильмов. В обоих случаях все работает, но дает очень большую нагрузку на ЦП телефона и он буквально становиться сковордкой на которй можно жарить яишницу. Если кончено сеть не глубокая и данных для обработки не много то можно и так, но почитав кучу статей понял что намного лучше релизвать нейросеть отдельно на сервере и общаться с ней по сети. На мой взгляд лучший фреймворк для НС это TensorFlow от гугла.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне реально совмещать. Нейронные сети используются в **Prisma** для обработки фотографий, в **Snapchat** для наложения масок(применяется распознавание лиц в реальном времени с помощью нейросети, а после уже применяются эффекты). В мобильном приложении **Auto.ru** нейронные сети дают возможность по фотографии найти нужный автомобиль в продаже. В целом, применение нейросетей широко, поэтому некоторые задачи и в мобильных приложениях с их помощью решаются очень эффективно. Особенно те, что связаны с распознаванием образов.

Пример реализации нейросетей на Java

[Нейронная сеть обучаемая по алгоритму обратного распространения ошибки](http://kenty-gwend.livejournal.com/461.html)

[нейронная сеть типа-многослойный перцептрон](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQnzc29PZ8)

Comment: А вот эти нейронные сети, которые в Мобильных Приложениях они тоже написаны на java?

Comment: Обычно в крупных приложениях данные(например фотография)  пользователя отправляются на сервер, а на нём уже происходит обработка с помощью нейросетей. Реализация, в плане выбора языка, у всех разная. Чаще всего для подобных решений используют python, и для него есть уже много готовых библиотек для нейросетей. Но нейросеть можно реализовать на любом языке, в том числе и на Java. Все зависит от задачи и ресурсов.

Comment: Кроме того, ваше приложение не обязательно должно взаимодействовать с сервером, нейросеть может быть написана и в самом приложении.